# iOS 13 PageSheet parent UIViewController not fading to black

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios13

I am migrating my app to support the new PageSheet style of `UIViewController` and I noticed that the view controller in the background is not fading like expected, it should get darker like visible in some examples on the internet. You can see the issue here (I draw a red line to show where the new `UIViewController` starts and where the old one is visible):

[image]

My app uses `UINavigationViewController` as root view controller, can this be the problem and is there any way to solve it?

I am not using any custom transition for the `UIViewController`s.

I am using Xcode 11.2.1.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I'm being asked to fix the same issue but can't find much info.

Comment: Mind your custom animations.